# Why should I use Platform.runlater on javafx main thread in this code?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm making java application with javaFx ui in kind of tiny machine. I wanted to show loading page, and load data files during the progress indicator going on.

I know it could work well if I added Platform.runlater on the code loading fxml file and controller, but it's weird for me to use Platform.runlater on javaFx main app thread. I checked threads' name but they were same. Also it works if it run separately using annotation.

Why do i need to use Platform.runlater ?

If I don't add that, loading image turns white screen and skip image, and just show menu view.

//Process

//1. Set loading page image

//2. Load data files

//3. Load next page(menu)

```
public void loadHomeMenuPage() {
    setLoadingImage();
    execLoadingData();
    execLoadingView(this);
}

private void setLoadingImage() {
    System.out.println("Load -> " + Thread.currentThread());

    File file = new File("Resources/images/load.png");
    InputStream is;

    try 
    {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        this.logoImageView.setImage(new Image(is));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

private void execLoadingData() {

    // load openCv files
    new LoadOpenCV();

    // load protocol files
    new ProtocolLoader().load();

    // load language pack here

}

private void execLoadingView(IController loadController) {

    //Load homeMenu after loading all data
    //Platform.runLater(() -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

                IController controller = (IController) FxmlUtils.LOAD
                        .fxmlPath(PathFxml.ABS_PATH_HOME_MENU_VIEW)
                        .pane("BorderPane")
                        .set2BaseBorderPane(this.baseBorderPane, "center")
                        .exec();

                controller.setBaseBorderPane(this.baseBorderPane);

    //});
}
```

Comment: You need to rethink your approach. You are running all the background loading on the JFX Application thread; this blocks your UI from updating until it's finished.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. You can simulate long process by using sleep.

Comment: @Zephyr thanks for reply. you mean, background loading data needs to be separated from fx app thread? I'll check soon

Comment: I did not propose it as a solution, but for the purpose of writting and posting mcve.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ;) Best to follow @c0der and provide the example ... asap, if you want "quick" help ..